# Error "'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" when iterating over list["a","b","c"]

Tags: python, syntax, literals

I'm new to Python and I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

when I try to run this code:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import*
env.workspace="F:\U of M\good good study\python\fl\fl"
inFeatures="foodpts.shp"
lst=list["ram","bak","cat","fas","far","fmk","sup","gro","ebt"]
for item in lst:
    populationField=item
    cellsize=100
    searchRadius=805
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")    
    outKernelDensity=KernelDensity(inFeatures,populationField,cellsize,searchRadius,  "SQUARE_KILOMETERS")
    outKernelDensity.save("F:\U of M\good good study\python\fl\fl\kernal")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And before you post another question, `"F:\U of M\"` is going to give you a `SyntaxError` about a `truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`. Double your backslashes to escape them (`"F:\\U of M\\"`), or use a _raw string literal_ (`r"F:\U of M\"`).

Comment: @BlacklightShining: A raw string won't do the job, since the final `"` will still be considered part of the string literal. (This behavior is necessary to allow people to put both kinds of quotes in the same raw string.)

Comment: I tweaked the title to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point. The asker can still use a raw string, though, since theirs doesn't end with a backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
lst=list["ram","bak","cat","fas","far","fmk","sup","gro","ebt"]
```

Python interprets what's in those square brackets as a key to get an item from what's just before them—in this case, getting the item with key `"ram", "bak", ...` from `list`. And, of course, the `list` class isn't a container and doesn't have any items!

Remove the leading `list`, and you get a list literal, which is probably what you want.

```
list_ = ["ram", "bak", "cat", "fas", "far", "fmk", "sup", "gro", "ebt"]
```

See [the documentation on `list`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) for more information on how to create them.

See also [the official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which states

- names that would otherwise collide with keywords or builtins (like `list`) should have single underscores appended rather than being mangled (`list_` instead of `lst` or `lizt`), except in the case of `cls`
- container literals and function calls should have spaces after the commas (`"ram", "bak"` instead of `"ram","bak"`)

Answer (score 1):

To define a list,

```
lst=["ram","bak","cat","fas","far","fmk","sup","gro","ebt"]
```

or

```
lst=list(...)
```

but `list` is a type, which you can call with parenthesis but you can't get an item from `list` using the square brackets.